# 18.04 nvidia instalation Quadro K2200 black screen

Tags: nvidia, 18.04

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 I get black screen. Only when I detach the card (Quadro K2200) I can I ca display Ubuntu on screen running from the main board output.

Everything was working well on Ubuntu 16.04

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The following worked:

sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

then remove the comment (# symbol) from the line that says

## WaylandEnable=false

and reboot the system